# How change image in wxStaticBitmap in C++

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

The compiler tells me that the program class doesn't contain an element named SetBitmap when I want to change the image in it

Solvo:

```
wxImage bildo("./bildo.png", wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);

objekto->SetBitmap(wxBitmap(bildo));
```

`objekto` is object with class `wxStaticBitmap`

Comment: can you please speak English? This is a public forum...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by Igor, it is better to speak english if you want a response.

> Compiler says that program class does not contain an element with name "SetBitmap" when I want to change an image in it.

You should post the part of your code, because wxStaticBitmap has a member named [SetBitmap](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/classwx_static_bitmap.html#ab612471da048963c7dae8942de29aef6)()

Comment: Ok. 

Solvo:
```
wxImage bildo("./bildo.png", wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);

objekto->SetBitmap(wxBitmap(bildo));
```